# Python: large projects and making changes to files used everywhere

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Suppose I had a large project in Java, and a class, UsedEverywhere, which was used everywhere. If I changed the return type of the returnsSomething method of that class, my IDE would tell me about everything that broke because of that change.  Now suppose I have a large project in Python with the same class and I make the same change.  There is no way for me to know what impact I have had unless I also have a huge suite of regression unit tests (which I use regularly).  This is due to the dynamic, duck typing system.  The same goes for a situation where I remove a method from a class that is used everywhere.  What is the best way to protect large projects from breaking without our knowing it?  These breakages would never be detected until some kind of regression testing is done.

Comment: Letting well-made unit and integration tests tell you about this is the *preferred* way to learn about the impact of the change. Relying on an IDE to tell you about it not only is not preferred; it's downright silly. I think your question is trying to be: "What to do if you failed to write good unit tests, failed to use abstract classes to validate interfaces, and failed to program defensively, and the return type of a function that's heavily used in your API suddenly changes?"

Comment: One solution I can offer is to build an adapter pattern around the class with the method that's changing. Use abstract base classes and implement whatever `__subclasshook__` you need (perhaps make a nice class decorator that takes an abstract class and adds `__subclasshook__` to check for the existence of specific methods). The wrapper class could convert the output of `returnSomething` as needed by the consumer classes, each of which should defensively assert that their own calls through to `returnSomething` give back the type they expect (as an extra contract on what the adapter can do).

Comment: You can use a product like PyCharm, which does some type checking, so long as you have well-written documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. Automated tests, as you've suggested.
2. Static analysis: Pylint, PyChecker and/or pyflakes.  Of these,
   pylint is the most stringent.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a situation where, just for the case of `returnSomething` you might want to use a "static typing" decorator, to ensure things about that function. I put "static typing" in scare quotes for two reasons. First, it's dumb and I tend to put dumb things in scare quotes. Second, doing this in Python is pretty hacky, so it's not like real static typing and you shouldn't think of it like that. (For example, this version will come with a runtime performance penalty for sure, whereas it would not if Python was a statically typed language.)

```
def ensure_return_type(permissible_types):
    from functools import wraps
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            potential_return = func(*args, **kwargs)
            if isinstance(potential_return, permissible_types):
                return potential_return
            else:
                err_msg = "Return value {} must be of type from {}".format(
                    potential_return, permissible_types)
                raise TypeError(err_msg)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Now consider a simple function like this:

```
def foo(x, y):
    return x + y
```

But what if no one anticipated that in Python this works just fine on `int`, `float`, *and* `str` inputs?

```
foo(1, 1)
# prints 2

foo(1.5, -1.5)
# prints 0.0

foo("foo", "bar")
# prints 'foobar'
```

So we try this:

```
typed_foo = ensure_return_type((int, float))(foo)
```

and we see

```
In [22]: typed_foo(1, 1)
Out[22]: 2

In [23]: typed_foo(1.5, -1.5)
Out[23]: 0.0

In [24]: typed_foo("foo", "bar")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-575a47c185e3> in <module>()
----> 1 typed_foo("foo", "bar")

<ipython-input-15-58b2c0884600> in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     10                 err_msg = "Return value {} must be of type from {}".format(
     11                     potential_return, permissible_types)
---> 12                 raise TypeError(err_msg)
     13         return wrapper
     14     return decorator

TypeError: Return value foobar must be of type from (<type 'int'>, <type 'float'>)
```

And of course, you would more simply use this with the common decorator syntax in Python at the time you defined `foo` in the first place:

```
@ensure_return_type((int, float))
def foo(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Or in your case:

```
@ensure_return_type((... <your_types_here> ... ))
def returnsSomething(*args, **kwargs):
    # stuff...
```

After you do this, you can easily control the `tuple` of permissible types that `returnsSomething` is allowed to return. This can be moved out of the code itself and into a parameter file or other form of metadata (where it belongs).

The other nice thing is that you can define an adapter class, like

```
class ReturnsSomethingAdapter(object):
    # stuff
```

This class could make heavy use of `@property` and Descriptor patterns to control read and write access to its internal data fields. Then you can make all of the downstream consumers of the output of `returnsSomething` plan to always expect an instance of `ReturnsSomethingAdapter`. When the consumers access data from `ReturnsSomethingAdapter`, maybe they can pass in their own class names or something, and the adapter knows how to modify output or re-format / re-type it for them to handle.

Inside of `ReturnsSomethingAdapter` (which should really inherit from an abstract Adapter of some sort), you should define `__subclasshook__` in such a way that whenever anyone else needs to check and see if they have received an instance of `ReturnsSomethingAdapter`, only the duck-typing interface of the adapter will be required for `isinstance` to return `True` (thus, any class with the same `@property` and Descriptor patterns can function in place of the adapter, allowing even more flexibility for things to change later.)

This sounds like a lot of work because it is a lot work. But at the same time, your large system seems like it needs guarantees about types that are passed around and the interfaces need to be verified and validated. So, you might have to pay a performance hit on that heavily used function if you must verify its output type. And in that case you want something flexible, which is why all these design ideas are needed.